# Is there a way to select a database from a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to select a database from a variable?

```
Declare @bob as varchar(50);
Set @bob = 'SweetDB';
GO
USE @bob
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Unless you can execute the rest of your batch as dynamic SQL.

Using `execute` to dynamically execute SQL will change the context for the scope of the `execute` statement, but will not leave a lasting effect on the scope you execute the `execute` statement from.

In other words, this:

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(100)
SET @db = 'SweetDB'
EXECUTE('use ' + @db)
```

Will not set the current database permanently, but if you altered the above code like this:

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(100)
SET @db = 'SweetDB'
EXECUTE('use ' + @db + ';select * from sysobjects')
select * from sysobjects
```

Then the result of those two queries will be different (assuming you're not in SweetDB already), since the first select, executed inside `execute` is executing in SweetDB, but the second isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @NewDB varchar(50)
set @NewDB = 'NewDB'
execute('use ' + @NewDB)
```

Comment: As per the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), "Changes in database context last only until the end of the EXECUTE statement.", so this code is documented as not giving the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

**#TempTables will presist across GOs**

you can create the table in the first batch, insert/select data as necessary in that or any following batch.

here is some sample syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTableName
(
     col1   int         not null   primary key   identity(1,1)
    ,col2   varchar(10)
)
```