# How to use the PRINT statement to track execution as stored procedure is running?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Reference: SQL Server

I have a stored procedure with a `while` loop in it and I want some messages to be printed after every 500 loops.

So, I've written -

```
CREATE spxxx
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        DECLARE @counter = 0;

        WHILE <somecondition>
            SET @counter = @counter + 1;

            IF @counter % 50 = 0
            BEGIN
                PRINT @counter;
            END
        END
     COMMIT TRAN
END -- End spxxx
```

But it prints all the messages once the proc ends. I want it to print the messages while its running.

Comment: sorry that was a type, i need the message every 50 loops.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm sure you can use [RAISERROR ... WITH NOWAIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

If you use severity 10 it's not an error. This also provides some handy formatting eg %s, %i and you can use state too to track where you are.

Comment: HI, thanks but i tried RAISERROR(@msg, 10, 1) with nowait;
and it still doesn't print anything :(

Comment: Try the following code:

    DECLARE @counter INT
 SET @counter = 0;

 DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(4)

    WHILE @counter < 1000
 BEGIN
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;

        IF @counter % 50 = 0
  BEGIN
   SET @msg = CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(4))
            RAISERROR (@msg, 10, 0 ) WITH NOWAIT
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  END

    END

Comment: Where are you running the code from? In SQL Management Studio, I can run this code and view the output as it is generated in the "Messages" tab of the query window.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server returns messages after a batch of statements has been executed. Normally, you'd use SQL `GO` to indicate the end of a batch and to retrieve the results:

```sql
PRINT '1'
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

PRINT '2'
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

PRINT '3'
GO
```

In this case, however, the `PRINT` statement you want returned immediately is in the middle of a loop, so the `PRINT` statements cannot be in their own batch. The only command I know of that will return in the middle of a batch is `RAISERROR (...) WITH NOWAIT`— which [@gbn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27535/gbn) has provided as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264635/3025856) as I type this.

Comment: :This is not working inside the SP but it is obvious inside Query Window.Is it??

Answer (score 0):

Can I just ask about the long term need for this facility - is it for debuging purposes?

If so, then you may want to consider using a proper debugger, such as the one found in Visual Studio, as this allows you to step through the procedure in a more controlled way, and avoids having to constantly add/remove PRINT statement from the procedure.

Just my opinion, but I prefer the debugger approach - for code and databases.

Comment: No long term need, I was just writing a data migration SP and wanted to see some results in the loop.

Comment: I found it useful for diagnosing performance problems by adding timings at various places. If done using a debugger the debugging process may affect the SP being measured.