# Can you print messages from within a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi Im trying to use `PRINT` or a none fatal RAISEERROR to print messages while my transaction is running but they will not print until the transaction has ended. is there any way to actually print a message from within a transaction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the PRINT statement to track execution as stored procedure is running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264586/how-to-use-the-print-statement-to-track-execution-as-stored-procedure-is-running)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll find it's buffering that's preventing the messages from printing.

Try:

```
raiserror ('hello', 0, 0) with nowait
```