# Python using Pyodbc connecting to Sql 2012 calling up a stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server-2012, pyodbc

I have a stored procedure that works 100% when run from the Sql server.  It updates at least 5 different tables.  When I run it from Python it only updates the first two tables.  Does not complete on the remaining tables.  The parameters passed are exactly the same as run from the sql server directly.  The data is reset to a common starting point with each test.  Has anyone come across this issue with Python execution of stored procs?  I am using Python 3.5 and Pyodbc from less than a month ago, Sql 2012 client and server on windows.  It is not a commit issue because the first two tables are updating/commiting.  The sql statement it fails on is not at all complex.  I am guessing some sort of limitation like time or only update so many tables with a given sql call?  My next step is to do each of the steps from Python as separate steps not from a single do everything Stored Proc to see if I get any differences but I am hoping to not have to do that.

```
str_rs_SqlCommand = "{call dbo.usp_LaborLogBatchPerson ('Test User', '1')}"  ### Passes parameters to the stored procedure 
print (str_rs_SqlCommand)
obj_dbc_Connection2 = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server} " + " ;SERVER=" + str_dbc_ServerName + " ;DATABASE=" + str_dbc_Name + " ;UID=" + str_dbc_Uid + " ;PWD=" + str_dbc_Pwd + "" + "" ) #;autocommit=True #tried with and without autocommit
conn = obj_dbc_Connection2.cursor()    ### Create a cursor for the sql connection 
conn.execute(str_rs_SqlCommand) 
conn.commit()
obj_dbc_Connection2.close
```

Comment: Without providing any code I am not sure what kind of help you are expecting...

Comment: Code is run from the command line not the web so there should be no time out issue as far as I am familiar with these technologies working together.  Please let me know if anyone has come across a time out issue when running from the command line.

Comment: What code is helpful?  A stored procedure with a bunch of inserts/updates.  I said the proc runs correctly when run from Sql server.  So the difference is when it runs from Python via pyodbc.

Comment: Would the stored proc help you?  The Python code that runs part of the stored procedure looks no different than when I do other stored procedures that are not as long and do only one thing.  That work fine.  The issue is not that the code does not work.  But that it works for some stored procedures but not for others.  The ones that work have only one table being updated.  This one works on the first 2 of over 5.

Comment: I would begin with showing the part of your Python code where the procedure is called. Then any relevant parts of your SQL (are their transactions being used, etc). I know you state it is "not a commit issue", but how is it that you are 100% certain that is the case?

Comment: Ok python code coming up.

Comment: There I think that is formatted right.  My first question still getting used to the forum, thanks for your help.

Comment: Update your post with the code - do not put it in the comments.

Comment: The python works and does not work depending on the stored procedure.  Simple ones it works on.  For instance I altered the SP it was failing on to do only one update, the proc called from python worked.  then I added the second updated, it worked again, then I added the third it failed.  Then I ran the same thing from the Sql server and it worked from the first three steps and from when I put back in all the code with more than five data updates.  I also notices Python did not let me created or drop tables.  Is there maybe some security setting I need to set?

Comment: All of the Sql connections are made from the SA user id so it is not a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found it by stepping through piece by piece of what it was doing.  Having a "Print Statement" in the stored procedure ends the execution of the stored procedure at that step.  Make sure you don't use print statements in stored procedures if you are using Python 3.5 with Pyodbc with MSSql 2012 on a Winderz platform......

Comment: Does anyone know how to trap for that error?  Assuming you get one from Python.  No error when executed with Sql client, stops running at that point when you run the same code from Python.

Comment: if you can edit the SP, and want to keep the equivalent of print statements, this seems relevant as a replacement http://stackoverflow.com/a/1264635/1007939 also [RAISERROR .. WITH NO WAIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that but I think it is not relative.  The Python ODBC dies if I do a print.  The print works with just Sql.  My understanding from other posts on the Python forum is that the Python expects a single Result Set.  It has some confusion issues if you return multiple result sets from the same Stored Proc or do print statements within the stored proc.  I also have not been able to get it to display the result set of a Stored Proc.  From a Sql select it works but does not appear to work from Python.  At this point I am concluding I have to make customized for Python execution Stored Procs

Comment: I was hoping someone out there may be familiar with getting your stored procedure for example that has prints, working with Python and Pyodbc from the command line.  So far I have not found an online example that works for that or one that can capture the result set coming back from a stored procedure.  I suspect a python data capture issue or perhaps it is a limitation of Odbc or Pyodbc.  Not sure at this point I am new to this combination of technologies and wondering if others have a deeper knowledge that my current level.  Thanks for the assistance though.

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem *per se* with `PRINT` statements in the SP because [this](http://pastebin.com/w8b9axkx) works fine for me.

Comment: There may not be a problem on your combination of tools but there is with mine.  I am using Python 3.5, Sql2012 server and odbc client, And latest Pyodbc on Windows.  What combination are you using?

Comment: I am having a lot of issues with 2012.  It may be related to that.  I have not tested it on other installs.

Comment: With the print statement in the stored proc it fails.  Remove the print statement and change nothing else, it works.  Clear indication of the Print statement causing the problem.

Comment: My test was with Python 3.5.1, pyodbc 3.0.10, and DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} hitting a local SQL Server 2008 R2 instance on Windows Vista.

Comment: That suggest we are different on Sql 2012 and that may be the reason we get different results.  Later when I have time I will try this from a Sql 2008 client to the same Sql 2012 server.  Thanks for the info that is very helpful.  I doubt the problem is the windows version.  My most likely suspected cause is the Sql 2012 client.  (much problems from this).