# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

`@RowFrom int`

`@RowTo int`

are both Global Input Params for the Stored Procedure, and since I am compiling the SQL query inside the Stored Procedure with T-SQL then using `Exec(@sqlstatement)` at the end of the stored procedure to show the result, it gives me this error when I try to use the `@RowFrom` or `@RowTo` inside the `@sqlstatement` variable that is executed.. it works fine otherwise.. please help.

```
"Must declare the scalar variable "@RowFrom"."
```

---

Also, I tried including the following in the `@sqlstatement` variable:

```
'Declare @Rt int'
'SET @Rt = ' + @RowTo
```

but `@RowTo` still doesn't pass its value to `@Rt`  and generates an error.

Comment: I won't add an answer because it doesn't apply to this question specifically, but as the first result on google for this error it's worth noting that using `GO` causes a new branch where declared variables aren't visible past the statement.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can't concatenate an int to a string. Instead of:

```
SET @sql = N'DECLARE @Rt int; SET @Rt = ' + @RowTo;
```

You need:

```
SET @sql = N'DECLARE @Rt int; SET @Rt = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @RowTo);
```

To help illustrate what's happening here. Let's say @RowTo = 5.

```
DECLARE @RowTo int;
SET @RowTo = 5;

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + CONVERT(varchar(12), @RowTo) + ' * 5';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

In order to build that into a string (even if ultimately it will be a number), I need to convert it. But as you can see, the number is still treated as a number when it's executed. The answer is 25, right?

In modern versions you can use `CONCAT()` to avoid handling `NULL` or conversion issues:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(N'SELECT ', @RowTo, ' * 5');
```

But in your case you should use proper parameterization rather than concatenation. If you keep using concatenation, you will expose yourself to SQL injection at some point (see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)):

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @RowFrom AND @RowTo;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@RowFrom int, @RowTo int',
  @RowFrom, @RowTo;
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the N' do?

Comment: It makes sure that your `@sql` variable is interpreted correctly as `NVARCHAR` - a requirement if using `sp_executesql`...

Comment: Well they need to be Int because its being used like this
"Where RowNum Between @RowFrom and @RowTo"

The param @RowFrom/@RowTo is int, as well as the Declared..

Comment: Yes, understood. You are building a SQL string, and you are on two levels of scope. At the top level, you are building a string - all that concatenation needs to be with string values, regardless of whether they are '5' or 'foo' or 'zuluxxy'. I'll add an example to illustrate.

Answer (score 34):

You can also get this error message if a variable is declared before a `GO`and referenced after it.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937336/is-there-a-way-to-persist-a-variable-across-a-go) and this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22918130/1431979).

Answer (score 7):

This is most likely not an answer to the issue itself, but this question pops up as first result when searching for `Sql declare scalar variable` hence I want to share a possible solution to this error.

In my case this error was caused by the use of `;` after a SQL statement. Just remove it and the error will be gone.

I guess the cause is the same as @IronSean already posted in a comment above:

> it's worth noting that using GO (or in this case ;) causes a new branch where declared variables aren't visible past the statement.

For example:

```
DECLARE @id int
SET @id = 78

SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @var; <-- remove this character to avoid the error message
SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE MyTableId = @var
```

Comment: This must be something _very specific_ to the editor you're using, or you've changed the batch separator in SSMS from `GO` to `;`. In T-SQL we are highly encouraged to always use a statement terminator (`;` is not a _batch_ terminator), and in fact there are many scenarios where you _have_ to use it. So I do not agree that removing it is a solution.

Comment: This should be considered as a hint. I have this issue in SSMS to this day and never have changed a setting, everything is default.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us (do you have any SSMS add-ins installed?) because there is no way a semi-colon is going to be considered a batch separator by SSMS on its own unless you tell it to.

Comment: (Though in your specific case it might be more related to mixing up `@id` and `@var`.)

Comment: This was my issue. Using `mssql-cli`

Comment: Thats it! SQLFiddle was driving me crazy till I simply removed the ; - characters.

Answer (score 6):

Just FYI, I know this is an old post, but depending on the database COLLATION settings you can get this error on a statement like this,

```
SET @sql = @Sql + ' WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @RowFrom AND @RowTo;';
```

if for example you typo the S in the

```
SET @sql = @***S***ql
```

sorry to spin off the answers already posted here, but this is an actual instance of the error reported.

Note also that the error will not display the capital S in the message, I am not sure why, but I think it is because the

```
Set @sql =
```

is on the left of the equal sign.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, if you have a 'GO' statement written after the usage of the variable, and if you try to use it after that, it throws such error. Try removing 'GO' statement if you have any.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding what fixed it for me, where misspelling is the suspect as per [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2010/03/03/must-declare-the-scalar-variable/)...

When splitting SQL strings over multiple lines, check that that you are comma separating your SQL string from your parameters (and not trying to concatenate them!) and not missing any spaces at the end of each split line. Not rocket science but hope I save someone a headache.

For example:

```
db.TableName.SqlQuery(
    "SELECT Id, Timestamp, User " +
    "FROM dbo.TableName " +
    "WHERE Timestamp >= @from " +
    "AND Timestamp <= @till;" + [USE COMMA NOT CONCATENATE!]
    new SqlParameter("from", from),
    new SqlParameter("till", till)),
    .ToListAsync()
    .Result;
```

Comment: this is true , i had missed comma and it gave me hard time to find. thanks for this hint, i was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Case Sensitivity will cause this problem, too.

@MyVariable and @myvariable are the same variables in SQL Server Man. Studio and will work. However, these variables will result in a "Must declare the scalar variable "@MyVariable" in Visual Studio (C#) due to case-sensitivity differences.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16 , the scope of a user-defined variable is batch dependent .

--This will produce the error

```
 GO   
    DECLARE @MyVariable int;
    SET @MyVariable = 1;
    GO --new batch of code
    SELECT @MyVariable--CAST(@MyVariable AS 
    int);
 GO
```

--This will not produce the error

```
 GO   
   DECLARE @MyVariable int;
   SET @MyVariable = 1;
   SELECT @MyVariable--CAST(@MyVariable AS int);
 GO
```

We get the same error when we try to pass a variable inside a dynamic SQL:

```
GO
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ColumnName = 'FirstName';
EXECUTE ('SELECT [Title],@ColumnName FROM Person.Person');  
GO
```

--In the case above @ColumnName is nowhere to be found, therefore we can either do:

```
EXECUTE ('SELECT [Title],' +@ColumnName+ ' FROM Person.Person');
```

or

```
GO
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ColumnName = 'FirstName';
SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @ColumnName + ' FROM Person.Person';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer for future me (maybe it helps someone else too!). If you try to run something like this in the query editor:

```
USE [Dbo]
GO

DECLARE @RC int

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure] 
   2018
  ,0
  ,'arg3'
GO

SELECT month, SUM(weight) AS weight, SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM SomeTable AS e 
WHERE year = @year AND type = 'M'
```

And you get the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@year"

That's because you are trying to run a bunch of code that includes **BOTH** the stored procedure execution **AND** the query below it (!). Just highlight the one you want to run or delete/comment out the one you are not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else comes across this question while no solution here made my sql file working, here's what my mistake was:

I have been exporting the contents of my database via the 'Generate Script' command of Microsofts' Server Management Studio and then doing some operations afterwards while inserting the generated data in another instance.

Due to the generated export, there have been a bunch of "GO" statements in the sql file.

What I didn't know was that variables declared at the top of a file aren't accessible as far as a GO statement is executed. **Therefore I had to remove the GO statements** in my sql file and the error "Must declare the scalar variable xy" was gone!

Answer (score 0):

Before writing code for inserting data with Dapper, first check if in your model class you have properly defined all the fields as properties.

Example -

```
public class Computer
{
    public string? MotherBoard { get; set; }
    public int CPUCore { get; set; }
    public bool HasWifi { get; set; }
    public bool HasLTE { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string? VideoCard { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you answered the wrong question? The question is about SQL-Server. How is C# and Dapper related?

Answer (score -1):

Give a 'GO' after the end statement and select all the statements then execute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).