# Issue with the variables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Declare @week1 varchar(max)='value 1'
Declare @week2 varchar(max)='value 2'
declare @sql varchar(max)
declare @i int=1
while(@i<=2)
begin
set @sql='print @week'+cast(@i as varchar(6))+''
exec(@sql)
set @i=@i+1
end
```

After executing this I am getting error saying:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2 Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@week1". Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2 Must declare the scalar
>   variable "@week2".

Comment: take at look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181976/must-declare-the-scalar-variable)

Comment: SQL which is executed doesn't contain the declaration for week1 or week2.

Comment: i need to print the values of @week1  and soon

Comment: I think your number of variables is fixed and you can use `CASE WHEN ` to print  it.

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue of scope. You can't access variable from within dynamic sql unless you declare them in the dynamic sql. If you change EXEC (@sql) to print(@sql), you'll see that what you're trying to execute is this...

```
print @week1
print @week2
```

If you're looking for the following result...

```
value 1
value 2
```

... then try altering your code to this...

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'DECLARE @week1 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''value 1'', @week2 VARCHAR(MAX) = ''value 2'';';
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
WHILE (@i <= 2)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' print @week' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(6)) + '';
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END;
EXEC (@sql);
```

... which generates and executes this...

```
DECLARE @week1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'value 1', @week2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'value 2'; print @week1 print @week2
```

Comment: i should not hard code the values  , actually those are parameters of a procedure here i mentioned like variables.