# Adding date and time to the backup file as suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create a job for taking backups in MSSQL Server Management Studio and run backup script periodically. I also want to add date and time as the following format:

2020.10.16_18.00.00

I tried some methods, ut I think I have to use special format. How can I get the date as above without using SP, etc. just using date-time methods?

I tried this but not exactly gives the format I want.

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 120)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add"?  Add to the filename?  Add to the data in the d/b?  Add to a log file?

Comment: Yes, add to the file name. Forget it, just concentrate on the format I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT` to customize the output:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm.ss')
```

Otherwise, you can manipulate the output with `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), '-', '.'), ':', '.'), ' ', '_')
```

This should allow you to define the path as variable:

```
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(500) = N'D:\backup\CurrencyExchange' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm') + '.log'
BACKUP LOG [CurrencyExchange] TO DISK = @Path
```

Comment: What about addinbg this to the backup script? I tries like that but not worked. Should I declare as a variable? How? `BACKUP LOG [CurrencyExchange]
   TO  DISK = N'D:\backup\CurrencyExchange' + SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm') + '.log'
GO`.

Comment: You can remove the `SELECT`, and that should work fine

Comment: Not worked, is there a special concatanation? Could you check please?

Comment: Maybe I need to convert to string?

Comment: I also tried like `BACKUP LOG [CurrencyExchange]    TO  DISK = N'D:\backup\CurrencyExchange' + SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm')) + '.bak'` but still not working.

Comment: Maybe try assigning to variable first: `DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(500) = N'D:\backup\CurrencyExchange' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm') + '.log'
BACKUP LOG [CurrencyExchange] TO  DISK = @Path`

Comment: Either way, you should not need the `SELECT`

Comment: Very strange, I also tried like that but gives *Must declare the scalar variable "@Path".* error. I also use `... + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm'))  + '.bak'`

Comment: I also tried to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181976/must-declare-the-scalar-variable But not solved

Comment: What if you try dynamic sql? `DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(N'BACKUP LOG [CurrencyExchange]
 TO DISK = ''D:\backup\CurrencyExchange{date}.log''', '{date}', FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy.MM.dd_hh.mm'))
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql`

Comment: But I do not want to use SP, just need a TSQL Backup script :(

Comment: Then I would think you'd have to go back to the variable approach. The `@Path` should be defined, but you have to run both statements together in same batch. I updated the answer with what I'd expect you would need.

Comment: This time OK, but what if I use the previous dynamic sql? Will it create a SP? I have not used synamic before.

Comment: The dynamic sql does not create any SP. It just uses the "sp_executesql" SP that is provided by SQL Server already (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thansk a lot, marked as answer. On the other hand, when creating job script, I think SQ Server Agent is also using the same SP in order to execute the job scripts given for the schedule. Any idea?