# Save Bigquery data in cloud Store day by day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a bigquery table event. Data comes from firebase. We have data from 2023 01 18 till today.

[image]

I want to migrate all previous data day per day in Cloud Storage, then for new days, having a cron for each day.

I created this script

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS ( 
  uri='gs://gara-store-firebase-events-bucket/event*.json',
  format='JSON',
  overwrite=true) AS

SELECT * FROM `gara-XXXXXX.analytics_247657392.events_20231101`;
```

I succeed to save this specific table in CS, but :

- I don't know how to iterate over each day
- I don't know how to add the date for example `20231101` in the name of the backup file created in CS.

Please, how could I do ?

Comment: Hi @Teddy Kossoko, can you check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions) for adding the date and you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64431190/adding-date-and-time-to-the-backup-file-as-suffix) also. I hope it will help you ?

Comment: Hi @Teddy Kossoko, can you confirm whether the above comment is helpful to you or not ?

Comment: @ArpitaShrivastava, i finally find another solution by creating a lambda, i send a request to bigqery to request the latest data, and save it to cloud storage.

Comment: Hi @Teddy Kossoko, I have posted the community answer, if my answer addressed your question, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Teddy Kossoko in the comment, create a lambda, and send a request to bigquery to request the latest data, and save it to cloud storage.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.